# What is the equivalent of explicit template instantiation in Rust's const generics?

Tags: rust

In C++ I can postpone the implementation of template types and functions such that I can provide only implementations for the types I explicitly support.

For example, I can provide in C++ only the versions of `doit<int32_t>` and `doit<int64_t>()` that are covered by my unit tests. This also has the upside to shorten the compilation times since the implementation of `doit<T>` is not recompiled at every compilation unit it is included.

```cpp
// File doit.h
template < typename T > void doit();

// File doit.cpp
template < typename T > void doit() { ...implementation... };
template void doit<int32_t>();
template void doit<uint32_t>();
```

How do I achieve the same with Rust's const generics?  For example, for the function below, I only want to provide implementations for BITS in `0..=5`.

```rust
pub fn ilog2< const BITS : u32 >( num: u64 ) -> u32 {
    let maxnum : u64 = 1u64 << BITS;
    if num<maxnum { return num as u32; }
    let mask : u64 = maxnum - 1;
    let msb : u32 = 63 - num.leading_zeros();
    let off : u64 =  (num >> (msb - BITS)) & mask;
    return  off as u32 + ((msb - BITS + 1) << BITS);
}
```

Comment: It's probably not good idea to try replicating C++ templates behavior with Rust generics. They are more like Rust macros. In particular, this is likely to be the case when they're different, since Rust generics are definition-checked, while C++ templates and Rust macros are instantiation-checked.

Answer (score 1):

The Rust solution to the first case is fairly straight-forward, you can constrain the generic type to have certain properties. In this case you can define a trait that is implemented for only `i32` and `u32`:

```
pub trait Is32BitInteger {}

impl Is32BitInteger for i32 {}
impl Is32BitInteger for u32 {}

pub fn doit<T>() where T: Is32BitInteger {}
```

However keep in mind that Rust generics only behave as they're constrained to behave. You'll need to add functions to the trait or add other constraints depending on what you want to do with `T` within `doit`.

---

Unfortunately, there isn't really a solution to the second case. Const generics in Rust are still taking their first steps, and as such there's a lot of limitations. I only know of two possibilities but both require incomplete nightly features:

- the first uses `feature(generic_const_exprs)` and the `Assert::<{...}>: IsTrue` trick that you might find on around the github issues on const generics: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=46d194efe1b886b864cb01ab45626b53).
- the second uses `feature(adt_const_params)` to make a wrapper type instead of `u32` whose invariant is that the value is constrained to `0..=5` that panics otherwise (causing a compiler error): [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e7b30d586f0c6f84894a1946afeba38f).

I wouldn't necessarily recommend using either of these due to their unstable nature. In the future, we may get syntax akin to `where BITS <= 5` more directly, maybe.

Comment: An `assert!(BITS <= 5)` might be another solution.

Comment: @Aiden4 that's maybe the most practical suggestion in this case. Just unfortunate that it causes the error at run-time instead of at compile-time

Comment: So is correct the understanding that I cannot export const generics at a binary level?

Comment: @kmdreko what about explicitly instantiating `ilog<0>`, `ilog<1>`, `ilog<2>` ... `ilog<5>`? If the user tries to use `ilog<6>` it would give a linker error.

Comment: @Jellyboy rust generics are NOT c++ templates, they're an extension of the type system, not the macro system. Your const generics should be read "for all values of u32 `BITS` there exists a function `ilog<BITS>`", so no matter what value `BITS` is the compiler will generate an appropriate function if it is referenced. The only ways you can cause monomorphization errors are with compiler bugs or by misusing intrinsics.

Comment: @Aiden4 so Rust generics cannot be exported as a library feature then. Is that correct?

Comment: @Jellyboy you can't directly export generics in a way callable from c. You need to basically monomorphize the generics yourself if you want to do that. You can still use generics within rust libraries though- there are libraries whose sole use is in generics, like [typenum](https://crates.io/crates/typenum) for example.

Comment: @Aiden4 I see. Well I have a use case where I provide a library to my clients and obviously I don't want to disclose the sources. Sounds like heresy but that's how I survive.

Comment: @Jellyboy see [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/41v5v1/is_it_possible_to_create_a_proprietary_library_in/) for more info on that; tldr good luck, you're gonna need it.

Comment: @Aiden4 Ok so perhaps it's more or less the same problem with C++ to some extent. Even if the ABI Is stable, nobody really uses a C++ interface for binary exports, everyone exposes a C API. I guess I can do the same.